# Error 999999, Table name is invalid - Zonal Stats as table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, zonal-statistics, iterator, error-999999

I am attempting to run a model that iterates rasters and computes zonal statistics returning a table. The raster's statistics are computer across all polygons in a specific shapefile. This model worked for a small amount of files (3), but when I am trying to use it for my entire Geodatabase it will not work, returning the error shown below. [image: Error 999999]

My model looks like this: [image: Model diagram]

I have around 300 rasters I am trying to find the statistics for, and they are listed in my geodatabase like this: [image: Catalog]

I am using the file pathway of a new folder followed by %Name% as shown in the Model Diagram. When executing the model non-iteravely,it completes when the file name is something random, say, "new", but when using the /%Name% as the file name, it returns that the characters are invalid.

I am very confused as to why this model worked for the test run of just a few files but not for the entire geodatabase.

Comment: try without blank spaces in your paths (eg E_MS_Epi_Theses). It often helps.

Comment: Done, still the same error.

Comment: Does NYS_ZCTAs share the same coordinate reference system as the input rasters?  If not, reproject those data and try again.

Comment: Reprojected, still the same error.

Comment: Could you try outputting them outside of a gdb? Do you have permissions to write to the folder ?

Comment: Yes I tried that as well. It seems to be having a ton of trouble naming the new tables.

Comment: try ending the table name with ".dbf" so something like c:\temp\%name%.dbf

Comment: You need to provide a file suffix for filesystem objects (`.dbf` or `.txt`)

Comment: Thanks for all the help everyone. So after changing the file name to %Name%.dbf, the model is running iteratively, but still returning me "Failed to execute" and with the same error about file names. However, when I go into arcCatalog, the dBASE tables are showing up as having been calculated. I am going to let the model run through all iterations and see if ArcMap is just confused with itself but still working.

Comment: Please always provide errors as formatted text rather than pictures.

Comment: I don't know if it would make any difference but you might try to create the tables within the gdb. In that case, you are not supposed to use any suffix. %name% should be fine.